# Query string param pass through to python lambda function not working

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, query-string

I'm trying to pass through parameters from a POST query string, I have followed forum responses such as Link: [https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=731341] 
to no avail. Starting out with the Hello-World example; this is my configuration, I am simply trying to pass through a value for 'foo'.

Lambda:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import json
print('Loading function')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    return event['foo']  # Echo back the first key value
    #raise Exception('Something went wrong')
```

To my API Gateway integration request /hello - POST - Method Execution I have added a query string entry for 'foo'.

I have also added the following integration request for an 'application/json' entry:

```
{
  "foo" : "$input.params('foo')"
}
```

Calling for example https://my-gateway-api.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/hello?foo=bar

Returns the following error:

```
{
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      10,
      "lambda_handler",
      "return event['foo']  # Echo back the first key value"
    ]
  ],
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "errorMessage": "'foo'"
}
```

I am guessing my integration template request is not transforming the incoming request as it should? Any pointers as to what I am doing wrong would be very much appreciated.

Comment: did you manage to solve it?